# Website Content load, Progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue in website loading progress bar. I am using below script for progress bar but its not working perfect in Web server www.example.com, website is hosted live in webserver but the issue is when I open the site the progress bar starts after a while.

How can I start progress bar as I open a website?

Thanks.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var width = 100,
    perfData = window.performance.timing, // The PerformanceTiming interface represents timing-related performance information for the given page.
    EstimatedTime = -(perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart),
    time = parseInt((EstimatedTime/1000)%60)*100;

    // Loadbar Animation
    $(".loadbar").animate({
      width: width + "%"
    }, time);

    // Loadbar Glow Animation
    $(".glow").animate({
      width: width + "%"
    }, time);

    // Percentage Increment Animation
    var PercentageID = $("#precent"),
        start = 0,
        end = 100,
        durataion = time;
        animateValue(PercentageID, start, end, durataion);

    function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {

      var range = end - start,
          current = start,
          increment = end > start? 1 : -1,
          stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
          obj = $(id);

      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        $(obj).text(current + "%");
          //obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
      }, stepTime);
    }

    // Fading Out Loadbar on Finised
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.preloader-wrap').fadeOut(300);
    }, time);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(document).ready(function(){` instead of `$(window).load(function(){`

> The `ready` event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded,
>   while the `onload` event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images)
>   also has been loaded.
>  The purpose of the `ready` event is that
>   it should occur as early as possible after the document has loaded, so
>   that code that adds functionality to the elements in the page doesn't
>   have to wait for all content to load.
> Credits to Guffa for answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698214/5883638)

So it's not waiting for the images, etc. are loaded. Only for the HTML document, which is loaded pretty fast.
Your code should look like this then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // all your other code    
});
```

---

Edit:
Try using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var width = 100,
      perfData = window.performance.timing,
      EstimatedTime = -(perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart),
      time = parseInt((EstimatedTime/1000)%60)*100;

  $(".loadbar").animate({
    width: width + "%"
  }, time);

  $(".glow").animate({
    width: width + "%"
  }, time);

  var PercentageID = $("#precent"),
      start = 0,
      end = 100,
      durataion = time;
      animateValue(PercentageID, start, end, durataion);

  function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {

    var range = end - start,
        current = start,
        increment = end > start? 1 : -1,
        stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
        obj = $(id);

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      current += increment;
      $(obj).text(current + "%");
      if (current == end) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, stepTime);
  }

  $(window).load(function(){
    $('.preloader-wrap').fadeOut(300);
    $('.wrap').fadeIn(300);
  });
});
```

The only condition to get that to work, is that you put all your content inside the `.wrap` div

Comment: But i have also an images at website , its working perfect for Html contents but , how to use this for images ?

Comment: I guess you got your code from this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/pen/MwppEB) right? I changed the code a bit. Try out [this codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/BROvQQ).

Comment: yeah i got this Code from here , but its not working perfect in my side , when i use this code with .load function its work as , as i mentioned above but if i use .ready its work perfect but webpage appear before images load. How can i fix it ?

Comment: It's edit tiiiime :) Try using the code I added to my answer